# Comparing two files using Awk in linux

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have two Files, File A and File B. The structure of the File A is mentioned shown below:

```
3314530275|76|1|20240422045006|
3335984469|64|2|20150804235959|
3367892381|203|3|20141025235959|
3369039388|203|4|20131219235959|
```

The contents of the second File B are given below:

```
3314530275|2000|999000000073101614|0|20370101000000|76|
3314530275|2000|999000000073101614|0|20370101000000|76|
3369039388|2000|812000002628721|-112|20360101235959|203|
3335984469|5037|5210367877660|180|20150213000000|64|
3335984469|5048|5210367877661|6|20150213000000|64|
3335984469|2000|812000002629182|1913|20360101235959|64|
3367892381|5014|5210365185964|419430400|20150308000000|203|
3367892381|5044|5210365185965|226020|20150308000000|203|
3367892381|2000|817000102009605|0|20360101235959|203|
```

The script should first check File A, if the third field ($3) is equal to 2, it should store the value of first ($1) and fourth column ($4).

Afterwards it will check if the $1 values (of the second file) are present in the values that we stored in the first step.

1. If the value is present and the second field is equal to 2000 it should print $1,$2,$4,(Value of the fourth column that we got from the first file and stored it)
2. If the value is present and the second field is not equal to 2000, it should print $1,$2,$4,$5

Sample Output in the above mentioned case:

```
3335984469|5037|180|20150213000000|
3335984469|5048|6|20150213000000|
3335984469|2000|1913|20150804235959|
```

This is what I have so far:

```bash
awk -F \| 'FNR==NR {if($3 == 2) a[$1] = $4; next} ($1 in a) {if($2==2000) print$1"|"$2"|"$4"|"a[$1]"|"} ($1 in a) {if($2!=2000) print$1"|"$2"|"$4"|"$5"|"} ' FileA FileB > Output_File
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I have come up with this uptil now but I am not sure if am using the code correctly because the output seems to be missing a lot of values that should be present --------------- awk -F \| 'FNR==NR {if($3 == 2) a[$1] = $4; next} ($1 in a) {if($2==2000) print$1"|"$2"|"$4"|"a[$1]"|"} ($1 in a) {if($2!=2000) print$1"|"$2"|"$4"|"$5"|"}  ' FileA FileB > Output_File

Comment: What am I looking for is an alternative way to achieve the same thing! My script works fine for a sample of values but when i use it on large files, the result is not the same

Comment: It looks like it should work, unless you have duplicate `$1` in file A. Do you have duplicate first fields in file A?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah, looks right. The only change I'd make is to fold the `if` and `else` into the same block: `$1 in a {if ($2 == 2000) print $1,$2,$4,a[$1],""; else print $1,$2,$4,$5,""}` -- implies `OFS="|"`

Comment: Or even `$1 in a {print $1,$2,$4,($2 == 2000 ? a[$1] : $5),""}`

Comment: What output do you actually get?

Comment: Is this line in your expected results correct "3335984469|2000|1913|20360101235959|" since your request is to print $1,$2,$4?. there is  $1,$2,$4 AND $5 in this line and $4 in this line does not match field $4 in file A here...i think i am little confuse here.

Comment: @Wintermute, I dont have duplicate entries in A.

Comment: @glennjackman, I am a little confused regarding this part of your code: 

`$2 == 2000 ? a[$1] : $5` 

can you explain how this works?

Comment: @Xorg, sorry about that! I edited the post! Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html#Conditional-Exp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script will work as-is given correct contents of fileA (`335984469` in FileA should be `3335984469`, i.e. one more leading `3`.) but it can be simplified to:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
FNR==NR { if ($3==2) a[$1] = $4; next }
$1 in a { print $1, $2, $4, ($2==200 ? a[$1] : $5), "" }

$ awk -f tst.awk fileA fileB
3335984469|5037|180|20150213000000|
3335984469|5048|6|20150213000000|
3335984469|2000|1913|20360101235959|
```

Feel free to cram it all back onto one line if you find that useful.

If the above doesn't work, check for the presence of control characters in both of your input files, the most likely being control_Ms as generously donated by Microsoft whenever their tools create files. You can check for them using `cat -v` and remove them with `dos2unix` or similar.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton. There was a typo in file A as you pointed out. I corrected my mistake.

Can you kindly explain how does `($2==2000 ? a[$1] : $5)` this part of the code works?

Comment: If `$2==2000` is true, the value `a[$1]` is returned, otherwise the value `$5`

Comment: @tripleee is correct and it's just a ternary expression, common to many languages - google "ternary expression".

Comment: Thanks @tripleee and Ed Morton!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"};FNR==NR{if($3==2){a[$1]=$4;next}};{if( $1 in a && $2==2000 ){print $1,$2,$4,a[$1]}else if ($1 in a && $2!=2000){print $1,$2,$4,$5}}' 'fileA'  'fileB'
```

adjustments that I have made to your command line to get the command line above

```
if( $1 in a && $2==2000 ){print $1,$2,$4,a[$1]}

else if ($1 in a && $2!=2000){print $1,$2,$4,$5}}
```

results

```
3335984469|5037|180|20150213000000
3335984469|5048|6|20150213000000
3335984469|2000|1913|20150804235959
```

Comment: This works as well but sorry @Xorg, i can only select one as correct answer! :(